# Access control in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

We have SharePoint portal developed on Office365, we have used access control to restrict the access from outside network and its working fine (we are not able to access the portal from outside network). but the issue was workflow are getting failed(They are getting triggered but when it try to access the SharePoint data its getting Unauthorized error as request is coming from SharePoint Workflow Server). we have tried white listing IP's listed by MSDN but still no luck.